# Морф. признаки сказуемого

Tags: сказуемые

Я буду танцевать вальс. Какое сказуемое в этом предложении? Если простое глагольное, то по какому слову определить время, переходность ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Буду танцевать" - аналитическая форма будущего времени (другой в русском для глаголов несовершенного вида просто нет). Все вместе (два слова) выполняет роль простого глагольного сказуемого. Не надо смешивать эти вещи.

***Переходность в аналитической форме будущего времени устанавливается по второму слову, знаменательному, время и лицо - по первому, вспомогательному глаголу.***

У **составного** глагольного сказуемого первый глагол тоже является знаменательным, смысловым. Он не просто служит для образования нужной видо-временной формы глагола, но и добавляет качество - отношение говорящего или ситуацию.

> Составное глагольное сказуемое
>
> Составное глагольное сказуемое состоит из связочной части и
>   неопределённой формы глагола. Отвечает на вопросы что делает? что
>   делать? что делал?Связочная часть может быть:
>
> фазисным глаголом (начать, продолжать, стать, бросить):
>
> Я начал / продолжил / закончил читать эту книгу.
>
> модальным словом (уметь, мочь, хотеть, желать, нужно, стараться, 
>   намереваться, осмелиться, отказаться, думать, предпочитать,
>   привыкнуть, любить, ненавидеть, остерегаться):
>
> Он хочет поступить в институт. Я долго не мог с ними встретиться.